# Accessing null value leads to application fail / C#

Tags: c#, reflection, null

I'm just looping and appending my properties to a big string:

```
output.Append(property.GetValue(this).ToString()));
```

When app breaks in that moment property represent a `ProductNumber` which is a `string`, value of this is `Product` object which has value of `ProductNumber = null`, so I've tried something like this:

```
output.Append(property.GetValue(this)?.ToString()));
```

But anyway **it breaks**..

How could I improve this code to avoid breaking there?

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: I suspect `property.GetValue(this)?.ToString()` works just fine and returns `null`. `output`'s `Append` method probably doesn't like `null`.

Comment: `output.Append(property.GetValue(this)?.ToString() ?? "");` if you want to `Append` empty string on `null`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That solves issue but I'm wondering why Safe Navigation Operator "?" didn't prevent app fail ? What's his purpose here? I thought I will avoid fail by putting "?" :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: `?.` either returns `null` if `GetValue(this)` is `null` or executes `.ToString()` and returns its outcome if `GetValue(this)` is **not** `null`. As you can see, `output.Append(null)` quite posible (when `GetValue(this)` returns `null`)

Comment: It did prevent an exception **in that location**, however, the expression now returns `null` instead of throwing an exception, and the next step was passing this `null` to `.Append` which thus failed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `output.Append` *complains* on `null` values. There are `2` possible sources of pesky `null`s here:

1. `property.GetValue(this)` returns `null` and thus `?.` in `?.ToString()` *propagates* `null`
2. `ToString()` itself returns `null` (hardly a case, but still possible)

We can solve both possibilities with `??` operator: let's return an *empty string* whatever the source of `null` is:

```
property.GetValue(this)?.ToString() ?? ""
```

Final code is

```
output.Append(property.GetValue(this)?.ToString() ?? "");
```

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
output.Append(property.GetValue(this)?.ToString()));
```

Is the same as:

```
object propValue = property.GetValue(this);
string propString = null;

if (propValue != null)
{
    propString = propValue.ToString();
}

output.Append(propString);  // propString can be null
```

This can be simplyfied like so:

```
string propString = property.GetValue(this)?.ToString();  // This performs a ToString if property.GetValue() is not null, otherwise propString will be null as well

output.Append(propValue);  // propValue can be null
```

If you want to prevent calling `Append` with a null value you can do:

```
string propString = property.GetValue(this)?.ToString();  // This performs a ToString if property.GetValue() is not null, otherwise propString will be null as well

if (propString == null)
{
    propString = string.Empty;
}

output.Append(propValue);  // propString is not null
```

This can be simplified with the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

```
string propString = property.GetValue(this)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty

output.Append(propValue);  // propString is not null
```